# AWS Cost Explorer API charges with Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

[This](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/pricing/) document says

> The AWS Cost Explorer API lets you directly
>   access the interactive, ad-hoc query engine that powers AWS Cost
>   Explorer. Each request will incur a cost of $0.01.

Does it hold true even if we access AWS Cost Explorer via Boto3? [Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html) doesn't mention anything to that effect. This caused me confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/pricing/) (the same link you provided), the AWS Cost Management services Cost Explorer API pricing is $0.01/request. This is true regardless of the programming language or SDK that you use to interact with the API.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I too believed same. But an opinion came saying: _The cost explorer API is priced. However, if we are using the boto SDK in our app, that will not incur us any charges._ So just wanted to listen from someone who has used these.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? This would be quite surprising.

Comment: No documented reference as such. But the one who told me said that they have been using cost explorer via Boto3 SDK and haven't seen their account being charged for CE service use. Now I've raised this with AWS customer service and let's see what they say.

Comment: Please do share the results; very interested to hear them.

Comment: Yes sure, will share.

Comment: Indeed there is confusion over Cost Explorer APi charges on various forums. Finally I contacted AWS customer care and this is what I got as their reply:

_Hello,

Further to our last email, we've received feedback from the relevant team and they've advised us that based on the information contained in the link that you provided, accessing Cost Explorer via boto3 would incur the same charges as the AWS Cost Explorer API.

I trust that this addresses your query but feel free to contact us if you require further assistance. 

Best regards,

Justin C
Amazon Web Services_